# PHP how get inner arrays from multidimensional arrays without using any for and foreach loops

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have an array as follows

```
$details = array([0] = array('id'=>1),
                 [1] = array('id'=>2),
                 [2] = array('id'=>3)
                );
```

Need to access the inner arrays without using any loops

Comment: `echo $details[0]['id']; // 1`

Comment: you get perticuler index value or get one after another

Comment: you know the index of inner array ?

Comment: Not any particular inner all inner arrays i want to print without using for and foreach loops

i need output like below
array('id'=>1);
array('id'=>2);
like this i want

Comment: Why cant you use loops? You could use a higher level abstraction like `array_map` but its still looping under the bonnet

Answer (score 0):

try `array_walk` php function to get inner array value

```
<?php
function myfunction($key,$value)
{
    print_r($key);

}

$details=array(0 => array('id'=>1),
                 1 => array('id'=>2),
                 2 => array('id'=>3)
                );

array_walk($details,"myfunction");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access nested arrays like so:

```
$details[0]['id']; //1
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
$innerArray = $details[0]; //array('id'=>1)
$innerArray['id']; //1
```

More details on this in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> **Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax**
>
> Array elements can be accessed using the array[key] syntax.
>
> Example #6 Accessing array elements
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array = array(
>     "foo" => "bar",
>     42    => 24,
>     "multi" => array(
>          "dimensional" => array(
>              "array" => "foo"
>          )
>     )
> );
>
> var_dump($array["foo"]);
> var_dump($array[42]);
> var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> string(3) "bar"
> int(24)
> string(3) "foo"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of your inner array you can access it using below statement:

```
$details = array([0] = array('id'=>1),[1] = array('id'=>2),[2] = array('id'=>3));

echo $details[$indexOfInnerArray]['id'];
```

where `$indexOfInnerArray` can be 0,1,2 ...